# Pytest diff failure for multiple files project layout

Tags: python, pytest, diff, python-import

Pytest (`pytest -vv ./testing.py`) is unable to show the diff with objects (spreadsheets and functions) being imported.
Any ideas on how to make it work (as if to show consistent diff across examples `test_one` and `test_two`) while preserving the layout? First test is omitting diff, which for sure is undesired behavior.

### Project layout:

```
pytest_so
├── src
│   ├── function.py
│   └── spreadsheets
│       └── sheet.py
└── testing.py
```

### ./testing.py

```
from src.spreadsheets.sheet import sheet
from src.function import function

def test_one():
    function(sheet)

def test_two():
    assert {'x': 1, 'y': 2} == {'x': 1, 'y': 3}
```

### ./src/function.py

```
def function(sheet):
    assert sheet[0] == sheet[1]
```

### ./src/spreadsheets/sheet.py

```
sheet = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
    {'a': 1, 'b': 3}
]
```

### Output:

```
====================================== FAILURES ======================================
______________________________________ test_one ______________________________________

    def test_one():
>       function(sheet)

pytest_so/testing.py:5: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

sheet = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}]

    def function(sheet):
>       assert sheet[0] == sheet[1]
E       AssertionError

pytest_so/src/function.py:2: AssertionError
______________________________________ test_two ______________________________________

    def test_two():
>       assert {'x': 1, 'y': 2} == {'x': 1, 'y': 3}
E       AssertionError: assert left == right failed.
E         Showing split diff:
E         
E         left:  {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
E         right: {'x': 1, 'y': 3}
E         
E         1 items in left, but not right:
E         + ('y', 2)
E         1 items in right, but not left:
E         - ('y', 3)

pytest_so/testing.py:8: AssertionError
============================== short test summary info ===============================
FAILED pytest_so/testing.py::test_one - AssertionError
FAILED pytest_so/testing.py::test_two - AssertionError: assert left == right failed.
================================= 2 failed in 0.08s ==================================
```

Comment: So, you have part of your tests in the source tree? Is this intended?

Comment: Yes of course, and the intention here is to preserve the following layout, no other option.

Answer (score 0):

In order for pytest to recognize test files that do not follow the usual pattern, you have to configure them. Create a `pytest.ini` in your root dir and add:

```
[pytest]
python_files = src/function.py
```

This gives the output:

```
================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________________________ test_two _________________________________

    def test_two():
        s = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}]
>       cmp_sheet(s)

assert_out.py:18:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

sheet = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}]

    def cmp_sheet(sheet):
>       assert sheet[0] == sheet[1]
E       AssertionError: assert {'a': 1, 'b': 2} == {'a': 1, 'b': 3}
E         Common items:
E         {'a': 1}
E         Differing items:
E         {'b': 2} != {'b': 3}
E         Full diff:
E         - {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
E         ?               ^
E         + {'a': 1, 'b': 3}
E         ?               ^

src\function.py:2: AssertionError
========================== 1 failed in 0.17 seconds ===========================
```